# ¿Se puede reemplazar el log de transacciones de la misma base de datos tomándolo de un respaldo?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Necesito disminuir el tamaño del log de transacciones de una base de datos, más sin embargo no puedo disminuirlo en el servidor donde está la instancia de la BDD por falta de espacio (justo por eso necesito disminuir el log). La cuestión es si puedo llevarme el log a otro equipo, ahí disminuirlo y luego reemplazarlo, el reemplazo lo pienso hacer directamente en la carpeta DATA ¿es posible hacerlo? ¿me daría problemas?

Answer (score 1):

No puedes dejar la base de datos sin log de transacciones porque es parte de la misma. Podrías llevarte la base de datos completa y después disminuir el tamaño.

Lo importante es que encuentres la razón por la que creció tanto el log. ¿Están haciendo respaldos constantes del log? Si no es así ¿Están consientes de que puede haber pérdida de información si se daña la base de datos? Si están dispuestos a aceptarlo y no quieren tener que respaldar el log constantemente ¿Podrían cambiar la base de datos a modo de recuperación simple? Si ya estaba en modo de recuperación simple ¿Que proceso hizo que creciera tanto?

En sí, es más fácil truncar el log si no lo vas a usar, pero necesitas estar consciente de las consecuencias de hacerlo. Para lograrlo, puedes usar estas instrucciones asignando los nombres adecuados.

```
ALTER DATABASE Nombre_BD SET RECOVERY simple
DBCC SHRINKFILE (Nombre_log , 100)
```

Comment: Cuando comento que pretendo llevarme el log a otro equipo para ahí disminuirlo no pretendo cortar el archivo sino llevarme una copia.  El tamaño del log es directamente proporcional a las actividades diarias que se realizan en la BDD. Tengo poco espacio en el disco duro porque es un servidor virtual que se creó con esa limitante. Se hacen respaldos deL log frecuentemente aunque para los respaldos diarios la base de datos está en modo de recuperación simple. Cuando respaldamos el log lo cambiamos a completo. Mi única duda es si puedo disminuir el log en otro equipo y luego reemplazarlo.

Comment: Es absurdo que estén cambiando el modo de recuperación a simple cuando hacen los respaldos de la base de datos. Básicamente están interrumpiendo el log de transacciones al hacer eso. Mover una copia del log no sirve de nada porque quedará obsoleto con cualquier cambio en la base de datos.

Comment: No lo cambiamos a simple, nuestra BDD está en modo simple y cuando queremos respaldar el log cambiamos el modelo de recuperación a completo (lo cual es correcto). Obviamente cuando tome una copia del log y lo reduzca en otro equipo no se ejecutará ningún movimiento en la BDD, no habrá ningún usuario conectado. Desde luego que tomaremos precauciones. Nuevamente, mi única duda es si se puede disminuir el log en otro equipo y luego reemplazarlo.